# Checking username/password combination is unique (do-while)

Tags: php

I'm working on a system where we need to create plain-text username/password combinations for users (it's not a particularly secure system, but it doesn't hold any information worth stealing anyway).

I'm trying to work a `do-while` loop that creates a random username/password, and then checks if there's a user in the database with that exact combination. If there is, it tries again. However, I get a blank screen when I run the following code, not even an error message:

```
do {
    $un = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++): $un .= chr(65 + mt_rand(0, 25)); endfor;
    $pw = rand(100000, 999999);
    $unpw_exists = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM table
                                        WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pw'");
} while (mysqli_num_rows($unpw_exists) > 0);
echo $un . " " . $pw;
```

Comment: Try to echo the $un and $pw inside the loop, so you'll get an idea what it's trying and how often the function runs. It might be trying the same thing a lot of times, or something like that.

Comment: Or better, [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) it.

Comment: You have an error, and no error handling code.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't correct `PHP` syntax:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++): $un .= chr(65 + mt_rand(0, 25)); end for;
```

Try:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++): $un .= chr(65 + mt_rand(0, 25)); endfor;
```

Or:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { $un .= chr(65 + mt_rand(0, 25)); }
```

Comment: My code is a valid alternative syntax for writing a for loop, which I find easier to read on one line: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Oh you are right! Sorry never realized that but should you have a space then? `endfor;`

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo.

My `for` loop should have ended as follows:

`endfor;`

and not

`end for;`